# Is BIOS/UEFI used after OS startup?

Tags: bios, kernel, uefi

I know that BIOS/UEFI is used during computer startup to boot the system and check HW and that it provides abstraction over hardware Does this mean, that the OS kernel calls  BIOS/UEFI layer when the OS is setup instead of interacting with hardware directly?